# How to fix "Formula Error: An unexpected error occured" in PhpSpreadSheet?

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpspreadsheet

[image: Formula]

I'm using PhpSpreadsheet to read .xlsx files, and one of the files I'm trying to import has this formula(image above).

I would get the error "**Formula Error: An unexpected error occurred**".

This is my code:

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$data= $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
```

If I try to set the 2nd argument to false:

```
$data= $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, false, true, true);
```

I won't get any errors but would return just the formula.

```
"=Table1[[#This Row],[Amount  With Tax ]]-Table1[[#This Row],[Tax]]"
```

How can I get the actual result base on the formula?

Comment: You use named Formula but that this isn't set. Try to use cell like A1 or B2 instead.

Comment: @Sundance_Raphael Unfortunately I'm not the one who created the file and I'm not allowed to change anything.

Comment: Unfortunately phpspreadsheet don't support named cells. Look at https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/ for more informations accessing cells. If you now the Colums you can overwrite the formular in phpspreadsheet with cell names (A1, B2, ...).

Comment: In my case, I am facing this error " Formula Error: Unexpected operator '&' ", but in my file, there is no formula. Don't get any workable solution through the internet