# PhpSpreadsheet: How I get calculated value from Xlsx cell. $cell->getCalculatedValue() return Formula Error

Tags: php, excel, import, codeigniter-4, phpspreadsheet

The 1st sheet of Xlsx is divided into 2 table names, Table1 and Table2.
The field formula is based on the table name and header name.

using $cell->getValue() I get
**=Table2[[#This Row],[PRODUCT PRICE]]+Table20[[#This Row],[COMMISSION PRICE]]**

I checked **PhpSpreadsheet** can read calculated values like  - **=E2/5 & =B2+F2**,

but how I get value from this type of calculation -
**=Table2[[#This Row],[PER DAY TOTAL]]/5**

**=Table2[[#This Row],[PRODUCT PRICE]]+Table20[[#This Row],[COMMISSION PRICE]]**

$cell->getCalculatedValue() give me this error-
[PhpSpreadsheet Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD1L7.png)

sheet row contains values like :

```
[1] => Array
(
    [0] => 1008
    [1] => 44659
    [2] => 1
    [3] => =Table2[[#This Row],[PER DAY TOTAL]]/5
    [4] => 975
    [5] => 
    [6] => Test
    [7] => Address
    [8] => JPY
    [9] => Zero
    [10] => 975
    [11] => =Table2[[#This Row],[PER DAY TOTAL]]/5
    [12] => =Table2[[#This Row],[PRODUCT PRICE]]+Table20[[#This Row],[COMMISSION PRICE]]
    [13] => 
)
```

Comment: [How to fix "Formula Error: An unexpected error occured" in PhpSpreadSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047338/how-to-fix-formula-error-an-unexpected-error-occured-in-phpspreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

So for this, you can use the below logic

```
  $calculetedValue=$cell->getOldCalculatedValue();
  
  if($calculetedValue=='' or $calculetedValue==NULL){
    $value=$cell->getValue();
  }else{
    $value=$cell->getOldCalculatedValue();
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).